# Can you access fromList within a Haskell function, without including the type in the function declaration, and if you can how to use it correctly?

Tags: haskell

I have a function declaration of:

```
iexec :: Instr -> Config -> Config
iexec (LOADI x) (counter, memory, stack) = (counter+1, memory, x:stack)
```

with Instr and Config being new Typeclasses.
I want this to work like so:

```
>iexec (LOADI 5) (0, empty, [])
>(1, fromList [], [5])
```

My issue is that I don't know how to return the fromList of the memory, everything else is working.
I tried doing

```
iexec (LOADI x) (counter, memory, stack) = (counter+1, Map.fromList memory, x:stack)
```

however I get an error, which varies based on the input, but it basically boils down to I don't know the correct syntax for this functionality, or I cannot access the fromList within a function.
Anything to point me in the right direction would be helpful, thank you.

EDIT:
As requested:

```
type Config = (Int, [Val] ,[Val])
```

where `Val` is an `Int`.
The error message when just using memory is:

```
error:
    • Variable not in scope: empty :: [Val]
    • Perhaps you meant ‘mempty’ (imported from Prelude)
  |
9 | main = print (iexec (LOADI 5) (0, empty, []))
```

Comment: Could you include the error message in your question please?

Comment: Please also post the definition of `Config`. I suspect it is something like `type Config = (Int, [(..., ...)], [Int])`.

Comment: What is wrong with just using `memory`? You should not use `fromList` here, since `memory` is already a `Map`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't think memory is a map at the moment, how would I make it a Map?

Comment: @EthanGallagher: because the second parameter is a `Config`, and the result is a `Config`, this thus means that if the second item of the 3-tuple of input is a `Map`, then `memory` is a map.

Comment: Based on your definition of `Config`, the second item of the 3-tuple (so the memory) is also a list `[Var]`, not a `Map Int Var` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found and understood:

The type config should be (Int, State, Stack) where State and Stack are:

```
type State = Map Vname Val
type Stack = [Val]
type Config = (Int, State, Stack)
```

Therefore, config can be put into the iexec function, and using the Data.Map functionality, both Val and Vname variables can be used, and fromList will be returned as the State is used as the "memory" and is a Map already.

Comment: How is this different from the second solution I proposed (`Config3` there)?

Comment: @DanielWagner it isn't technically it is just fitting the specification for the project better.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a type signature that says you return a list, then you cannot return a map instead. So the answer to the question in the title is "No, you can't do that.".

There are a variety of options for alternative plans. One would be to parameterize your `Config` type. Assuming you have imported your favorite map implementation module as `M`, that would look like this:

```
type Config2 f = (Int, f Val, [Val])

iexec2 :: Instr -> Config2 [] -> Config2 (M.Map Int)
iexec2 (LOADI x) (counter, memory, stack) = (counter+1, M.fromList (zip [0..] memory), x:stack)

main = print (iexec2 (LOADI 5) (0, [], []))
```

Another option would be to just change your `Config` type to always be a map:

```
type Config3 = (Int, M.Map Int Val, [Val])

iexec3 :: Instr -> Config3 -> Config3
iexec3 (LOADI x) (counter, memory, stack) = (counter+1, memory, x:stack)

main = print (iexec3 (LOADI 5) (0, M.empty, []))
```

There are further options, but I think these two are the cleanest.